# composer-plugin-api error when installing dependencies

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I'm trying to install dependencies for an existing Symfony project I'm trying to work on.  I looked at this https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#composer-lock-the-lock-file and it says that I should run the update command: `php composer.phar update`. I did that, but I get the following error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - phpro/grumphp[v0.12.0, ..., v0.12.1] require composer-plugin-api ~1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.1.0] but it does not match the constraint.
    - Root composer.json requires phpro/grumphp ^0.12 -> satisfiable by phpro/grumphp[v0.12.0, v0.12.1].
```

Comment: Check your composer.json and see if you have `composer-plugin-api` on it!
If you don't have it, then install it using `composer require composer-plugin-api` and then try again with `composer update` .

Comment: @DhiaDjobbi I tried installing composer-plugin-api. At first it says composer.json has been updated, then it says "Loading composer repositories with package information.   Updating dependencies (including require-dev)" then it says "Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content."

Comment: @DhiaDjobbi you cannot install `composer-plugin-api` itself, that is provided by Composer

Answer (score 6):

Seems to be it needs composer 1. Try delete the vendor folder and downgrade composer with `composer self-update --1`. Than run `composer install` or `composer update` again.

Comment: `Command "self-update" is not defined.`

Answer (score 0):

As a **Windows 11** user,
The same issue was found with laravel 10. X. X (latest version). Need to update the composer but "Windows 11" and above do not allow commands like "composer self-update". So I downloaded a new composer.exe from the web [composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/) and installed it again(without removing the older one), It'll update automatically and it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

> `require composer-plugin-api ~1.0`

That part from the error messages tells you that any of the packages you are using requires the API provided by Composer v1. In some cases, there is only one solution to this problem: downgrade Composer to v1 to use the packages you are currently using. But this is not a long-term solution, as [Packagist has deprecated its support for v1](https://blog.packagist.com/deprecating-composer-1-support/). Also, v2 of Composer brings [huge performance improvements](https://blog.packagist.com/composer-2-0-is-now-available/), so updating brings real benefits :)

In your specific case, `phpro/grumphp` is requiring the old API. You are using a pretty old version, as the version constraint `^0.12` does only match two versions of that package, which are 0.12.0 (released in September 2017), and 0.12.1 (released in November 2017). Since 0.18.1 (released in May 2020), this package supports both Composer v1 and v2, so updating this package to 0.18.1 or laters helps to resolve your problem without downgrading to Composer v1.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I already downgraded the composer. The current version is 1.4.1 But still having trouble

Comment: If you have trouble with anything, please open a new question